# Azure Durable functions For high throughput / low latency?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I would like to build an IOT system capable of receiving messages every second or even less from a device, and maintain a state. (Think state machine / alarms).

Is this scenario something that Azure Durable functions would work with, or should I take a more classical approach? Especially thinking about delays and throughput.

Comment: Have you looked in to stream analytics?

Comment: I guess it will depends on what you are doing with the data after. If you use Azure Function with `EventHubTrigger` is should be all go

Comment: I am using IotHubTrigger. The question is more how much the Durable framework is suitable for high throughput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, Durable Functions by itself isn't great for low-latency scenarios. This is because it relies heavily on queue messaging, which means there will be delays between polling intervals. For your scenario, you may want to look into a more classical low-latency actor model.